# jquery access in a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've recently implemented a jquery script to convert a html table into a excel file.
I've written this script inside a php file, but when i try to get the code working the only thing i get is a reference error in firefox:

ReferenceError: $datatype is not defined

I think the php interpreter doesn't ignore $datatype as jquery but try to use it as a php variable.
Is there any kind of solution to get jquery code function inside a php file?
Thanks for any suggestion

```
<?php 
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['locazione']= $_GET['locazione'];
        //echo  $_SESSION['locazione'];
        ?>
<html>
    <head>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>
                <script src="./js/jquery.btechco.excelexport.js"></script>
                <script src="./js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <link href="./css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <?php $Locazione = $_GET['locazione']; ?>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#btnExport").click(function () {
                        $("#tblExport").btechco_excelexport({
                            containerid: "tblExport",
                            datatype: $datatype.Table
                        });
                    });
                });
                </script>
        <!-- [...] -->
    </head>
        <body>      

        <INPUT type="button" value="Aggiungi Elemento" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
        <INPUT type="button" value="Elimina Elemento" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
        <form action="form.php" method="post" name="f" style="position: relative;">  
        <TABLE id="tblExport" border="0"style="width:100%;min-height:50px;top:10px">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="35"></th>
            <th width="54" align="left">TipoLocale</th>
            <th width="54" align="left">NomeLocale</th>
            <th width="54" align="left">NumeroLocale</th>
            <th width="54" align="left">TipoCarico</th>
            <th width="54">N°</th>
            <th width="54" align="left">Potenza</th>
            <th width="54" align="left">PotenzaTotale</th>
            <th width="54">Note</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="dataTable">
        </tbody>
        </TABLE>
        <div id="sendbtn">
        <INPUT type="submit" value="Invia" name="submit" target="_new"  onclick="return confirm('Confermi l\'inserimento?')"/>
            <input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />       
        </div>
        </form>             
        </body>
        </html>
```

this is the jquery.btechco.excelexport.js:

```
(function ($) {

   var $datatype = {
        Table: 1
        , Json: 2
        , Xml: 3
        , JqGrid: 4
    }

var $defaults = {
    containerid: null
    , datatype: $datatype.Table
    , dataset: null
    , columns: null
};

var $settings = $defaults;

$.fn.btechco_excelexport = function (options) {
    $settings = $.extend({}, $defaults, options);

    switch ($settings.datatype) {
        case 1:
            Export($("#" + $settings.containerid).parent().html());
            break;
        case 2:
            Export(ConvertJsonToTable());
            break;
        case 3:
            Export(ConvertXmlToTable());
            break;
        case 4:
            Export(ConvertJqGridDataToTable());
            break;
    }

    function ConvertJsonToTable() {
        var result = "<table>";

        result += "<thead><tr>";
        $($settings.columns).each(function (key, value) {
            if (this.ishidden != true) {
                result += "<th";
                if (this.width != null) {
                    result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                }
                result += ">";
                result += this.headertext;
                result += "</th>";
            }
        });
        result += "</tr></thead>";

        result += "<tbody>";
        $($settings.dataset).each(function (key, value) {
            result += "<tr>";
            $($settings.columns).each(function (k, v) {
                if (value.hasOwnProperty(this.datafield)) {
                    if (this.ishidden != true) {
                        result += "<td";
                        if (this.width != null) {
                            result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                        }
                        result += ">";
                        result += value[this.datafield];
                        result += "</td>";
                    }
                }
            });
            result += "</tr>";
        });
        result += "</tbody>";

        result += "</table>";
        return result;
    }

    function ConvertXmlToTable() {
        var result = "<table>";

        result += "<thead><tr>";
        $($settings.columns).each(function (key, value) {
            if (this.ishidden != true) {
                result += "<th";
                if (this.width != null) {
                    result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                }
                result += ">";
                result += this.headertext;
                result += "</th>";
            }
        });
        result += "</tr></thead>";

        result += "<tbody>";
        $($settings.dataset).find("row").each(function (key, value) {
            result += "<tr>";
            $($settings.columns).each(function (k, v) {
                if ($(value).attr(this.datafield)) {
                    if (this.ishidden != true) {
                        result += "<td";
                        if (this.width != null) {
                            result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                        }
                        result += ">";
                        result += $(value).attr(this.datafield);
                        result += "</td>";
                    }
                }
            });
            result += "</tr>";
        });
        result += "</tbody>";

        result += "</table>";
        return result;
    }

    function ConvertJqGridDataToTable() {
        var result = "<table>";

        result += "<thead><tr>";
        $($settings.columns).each(function (key, value) {
            if (this.ishidden != true) {
                result += "<th";
                if (this.width != null) {
                    result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                }
                result += ">";
                result += this.headertext;
                result += "</th>";
            }
        });
        result += "</tr></thead>";
        result += "<tbody>";

        $($settings.dataset).find("rows > row").each(function (key, value) {
            result += "<tr>";
            $($settings.columns).each(function (k, v) {
                if ($(value).find(this.datafield)) {
                    if (this.ishidden != true) {
                        result += "<td";
                        if (this.width != null) {
                            result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                        }
                        result += ">";
                        result += $(value).find(this.datafield).text();
                        result += "</td>";
                    }
                }
            });
            result += "</tr>";
        });
        result += "</tbody>";

        result += "</table>";
        return result;
    }

    function Export(htmltable) {
        var excelFile = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>";
        excelFile += "<head>";
        excelFile += "<!--[if gte mso 9]>";
        excelFile += "<xml>";
        excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorkbook>";
        excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorksheets>";
        excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorksheet>";
        excelFile += "<x:Name>";
        excelFile += "{worksheet}";
        excelFile += "</x:Name>";
        excelFile += "<x:WorksheetOptions>";
        excelFile += "<x:DisplayGridlines/>";
        excelFile += "</x:WorksheetOptions>";
        excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorksheet>";
        excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorksheets>";
        excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorkbook>";
        excelFile += "</xml>";
        excelFile += "<![endif]-->";
        excelFile += "</head>";
        excelFile += "<body>";
        excelFile += htmltable.replace(/"/g, '\'');
        excelFile += "</body>";
        excelFile += "</html>";

        var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(excelFile);
        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel;filename=test;' + base64data);
    }
};
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {

   var $datatype = {
        Table: 1
        , Json: 2
        , Xml: 3
        , JqGrid: 4
    }

var $defaults = {
    containerid: null
    , datatype: $datatype.Table
    , dataset: null
    , columns: null
};

var $settings = $defaults;

$.fn.btechco_excelexport = function (options) {
    $settings = $.extend({}, $defaults, options);

    switch ($settings.datatype) {
        case 1:
            Export($("#" + $settings.containerid).parent().html());
            break;
        case 2:
            Export(ConvertJsonToTable());
            break;
        case 3:
            Export(ConvertXmlToTable());
            break;
        case 4:
            Export(ConvertJqGridDataToTable());
            break;
    }

    function ConvertJsonToTable() {
        var result = "<table>";

        result += "<thead><tr>";
        $($settings.columns).each(function (key, value) {
            if (this.ishidden != true) {
                result += "<th";
                if (this.width != null) {
                    result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                }
                result += ">";
                result += this.headertext;
                result += "</th>";
            }
        });
        result += "</tr></thead>";

        result += "<tbody>";
        $($settings.dataset).each(function (key, value) {
            result += "<tr>";
            $($settings.columns).each(function (k, v) {
                if (value.hasOwnProperty(this.datafield)) {
                    if (this.ishidden != true) {
                        result += "<td";
                        if (this.width != null) {
                            result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                        }
                        result += ">";
                        result += value[this.datafield];
                        result += "</td>";
                    }
                }
            });
            result += "</tr>";
        });
        result += "</tbody>";

        result += "</table>";
        return result;
    }

    function ConvertXmlToTable() {
        var result = "<table>";

        result += "<thead><tr>";
        $($settings.columns).each(function (key, value) {
            if (this.ishidden != true) {
                result += "<th";
                if (this.width != null) {
                    result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                }
                result += ">";
                result += this.headertext;
                result += "</th>";
            }
        });
        result += "</tr></thead>";

        result += "<tbody>";
        $($settings.dataset).find("row").each(function (key, value) {
            result += "<tr>";
            $($settings.columns).each(function (k, v) {
                if ($(value).attr(this.datafield)) {
                    if (this.ishidden != true) {
                        result += "<td";
                        if (this.width != null) {
                            result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                        }
                        result += ">";
                        result += $(value).attr(this.datafield);
                        result += "</td>";
                    }
                }
            });
            result += "</tr>";
        });
        result += "</tbody>";

        result += "</table>";
        return result;
    }

    function ConvertJqGridDataToTable() {
        var result = "<table>";

        result += "<thead><tr>";
        $($settings.columns).each(function (key, value) {
            if (this.ishidden != true) {
                result += "<th";
                if (this.width != null) {
                    result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                }
                result += ">";
                result += this.headertext;
                result += "</th>";
            }
        });
        result += "</tr></thead>";
        result += "<tbody>";

        $($settings.dataset).find("rows > row").each(function (key, value) {
            result += "<tr>";
            $($settings.columns).each(function (k, v) {
                if ($(value).find(this.datafield)) {
                    if (this.ishidden != true) {
                        result += "<td";
                        if (this.width != null) {
                            result += " style='width: " + this.width + "'";
                        }
                        result += ">";
                        result += $(value).find(this.datafield).text();
                        result += "</td>";
                    }
                }
            });
            result += "</tr>";
        });
        result += "</tbody>";

        result += "</table>";
        return result;
    }

    function Export(htmltable) {
        var excelFile = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>";
        excelFile += "<head>";
        excelFile += "<!--[if gte mso 9]>";
        excelFile += "<xml>";
        excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorkbook>";
        excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorksheets>";
        excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorksheet>";
        excelFile += "<x:Name>";
        excelFile += "{worksheet}";
        excelFile += "</x:Name>";
        excelFile += "<x:WorksheetOptions>";
        excelFile += "<x:DisplayGridlines/>";
        excelFile += "</x:WorksheetOptions>";
        excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorksheet>";
        excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorksheets>";
        excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorkbook>";
        excelFile += "</xml>";
        excelFile += "<![endif]-->";
        excelFile += "</head>";
        excelFile += "<body>";
        excelFile += htmltable.replace(/"/g, '\'');
        excelFile += "</body>";
        excelFile += "</html>";

        var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(excelFile);
        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel;filename=test;' + base64data);
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: No, PHP doesn't interpret your $datatype variable as a PHP variable. As the error says, $datatype is not defined in your javascript. Where is $datatype defined in your code?

Comment: $datatype is defined in ./js/jquery.btechco.excelexport.js script. i've tried do add var as @RohitBatham suggested but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {

   var $datatype = {
        Table: 1
        , Json: 2
        , Xml: 3
        , JqGrid: 4
    }
```

In your library( jquery.battatech.excelexport.js), add var before the $datatype

Comment: the hilariuos thing is the example code available from https://github.com/battatech/battatech_excelexport is corretly functioning!(but no php code)

Answer (score 0):

Such i newbie that i am!
The solution is so simple that i didn't recognize before.
My loading script order was wrong.
I loaded the export.js before the jquery.js, calling the jquery functions before the script!
The fault one:

```
<script src="./js/jquery.btechco.excelexport.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The right one:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.btechco.excelexport.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
```

Sorry for the dumb question
Thanks for your help